# Convert Multiple Stereo MP3 Files into their Mono WAV Equivalents?

Tags: audio, mp3, converters, wav

My question is exactly as is mentioned above. I have a set of files names 1.mp3, 2.mp3 and so on that I have to convert to mono .wav files. I know how to do this in audacity. But is there any faster way to possibly achieve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which platform you use(i.e., Windows, OSX, Linux).

Assuming Windows, you can use this: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Audio-Convertors/Free-WAV-MP3-Converter.shtml

Don't install any of the extra stuff. Be forewarned - converting from MP3 to WAV is going from a lossy compression to a lossless one, and won't sound that great.

Online you can do them one by one with:
 http://www.zamzar.com/

or any of a million other online file conversion sites. This will necessarily be just as slow as using audacity.